# Media Queries bagunçando o site

Tags: html, css

Galera, seguinte.

Já possuo 4 **CSS** que fazem os ajustes necessários no meu site. 
(infelizmente comecei do maior para o menor, já que eu não sabia que era bom ter começado do mobile).

Pro meu site será preciso:

- Um css que apareça **a partir** de 1200px até qualquer tela maior que isso;
- Um css que apareça **abaixo** deste 1200px até 1024px (irei abaixando)
- Um css que apareça **abaixo** deste 1024px até 883px.

E agora estou criando um novo css, que usarei abaixo deste 883px. Porém, quando coloco este código no meu css, um css menor junta com um css maior e os dois ficam na página, bagunçando tudo. Como faço pra usar 1 css de cada vez em cada área que especifiquei?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 883px)" href="css/minsmall.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 1023px)" href="css/small.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1024px)" href="css/medium.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1200px)" href="css/large.css">
```

Uma outra pergunta: Num exemplo eu vi que o cara usou no media=" screen and [...] ao invés de only screen [...], qual a diferença de usar only ou deixar sem o only? "

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o navegador pode interpretar por exemplo que o tamanho máximo de até 1024 px tem 3 css que poderiam ser utilizados. Você não pode colocar um min-width antes do max? Assim faria intervalos mais precisos...

Comment: então, é que não sei muito como ficaria, poderia fazer um exemplo qualquer do codigo de como ficaria?

Comment: Respondi abaixo pra ficar mais fácil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executa o código abaixo e muda a resolução da sua página (Pode mexer na largura da janela)

Obs.: É possível que não funcione aqui no stack. Copie e coloque no arquivo em sua máquina. Só testar...

```css
#btn{
background: #FF0000;
}

@media all and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px){
  #btn{
    background: #00FF00;
  }
}


@media all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px){
  #btn{
    background: #0000FF;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Teste</button>
```

Comment: neste caso, você está utilizando a mudança num unico css, que geralmente é para pequenas mudanças, no meu é necessário a mudança do css inteiro pq tem algumas grandes modificações, e eu já tenho cada css pronto..
só estou com dificuldade de configurar este codigo que eu coloco no html "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 883px)" href="css/minsmall.css">"

Comment: Veja desta forma: "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 883px)" href="css/minsmall.css">"

Comment: Ei, funcionou! MUUUUITO OBRIGADO.
Se puder atualizar sua resposta, com este código que você comentou, só pra ficar certinho a resposta da pergunta para outras pessoas.